# search through the string from last and find the second occurrence of a string

Tags: c#, string, ssis, string-parsing

I have one requirement to search the string and need to find second occurrence  of the same string from last(ascending order) and have to read it from that search string to last in a file.

Example String:

```
START BATCH;Cube check SUCCESS;Cube Check Status Time;2/22/2017 5:54:02AM; Entered try;Web check Passed;STOP BATCH;START BATCH;Cube check SUCCESS;Cube Check Status Time
```

from this semicolon separated string i need to search the second re- occurring  string `START BATCH` from the last(down to up) then from that string i need to  store that whole sub-string into string array.

Earlier i am able to get the string through LastIndexof method. But this time i  need to get the second occurrence of the same string.
Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`LastIndexOf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc3z4t9d(v=vs.110).aspx) version that takes a `startIndex` argument:

```
public int FindSecondLastIndex(string input, string search)
{
    int lastIndex = input.LastIndexOf(search);
    if (lastIndex <= 0) return -1;
    return input.LastIndexOf(search, lastIndex - 1);
}
```

and use it:

```
string input = "START BATCH;Cube check SUCCESS;Cube Check Status Time;2/22/2017 5:54:02AM; Entered try;Web check Passed;STOP BATCH;START BATCH;Cube check SUCCESS;Cube Check Status Time"
string search = "START BATCH";

Console.WriteLine(FindSecondLastIndex(input, search));
```

Output: `0`.

---

You can improve performance a little bit by checking the length:

```
if (lastIndex < search.Length) return -1;
return input.LastIndexOf(search, lastIndex - search.Length);
```

---

And probably implement it as extension for `string`:

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static int SecondLastIndexOf(this string input, string search)
    { ... }
}
```

so you can use it like

```
var index = input.SecondLastIndexOf(search);
```

Comment: Vogt i am aware of this logic. once i find the second occurance of string i need to store the string in string array from that searched string to end of the string.

Comment: @VigneshR please clarify your wording. Specify what _exactly_ you mean by "storing the string in string array". I _guess_ you mean to _split_ it by `;`. But that is only a guess, you may mean something totally different. Please edit your question and provide an example and _specific_ criteria for splitting the string (_if_ splitting is what you mean).

Comment: @Vogt the above code has worked for me. Thanks a lot for your suggestion..